# python time measure for every function

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, time

I just completed writing my first program in python, i have written all my functions in a single module, i just executed it from command line by giving the input files as argument and it worked. But when i gave a big dataset, my program continuously running for some time. Now my next step is to find which function is taking more time in my module. I could get the time taken by whole program, but i need for each function separately.

I tried to understand timeit and profile modules in python, but as per my understanding, they were giving the time taken by a particular function. Is there a way to know the time taken by each function in my module as a statistics( all at once )?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [*this*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the terminal, run

```
python -m profile -s time file.py
```

or

```
python -m cProfile -s time file.py
```

The second can be faster, and is never worse.

This will give something like:

```
   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       39    0.132    0.003    0.139    0.004 :0(load_dynamic)
      239    0.097    0.000    0.097    0.000 :0(loads)
    541/1    0.083    0.000    3.556    3.556 :0(exec)
       30    0.082    0.003    0.082    0.003 :0(statusBar)
                        ... etc ...
```

The left hand side will contain your functions.

Comment: Am getting these errors --> File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/profile.py", line 589, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/profile.py", line 575, in main
    code = compile(fp.read(), progname, 'exec')
  File "/home/****/eclipseworkspace/abcd.py", line 20
    print '%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec' % \

Comment: What happens if you just run `python file.py`?

Comment: Also, what does `python -V` say? It should start with "Python 2".

Comment: I have both 2.7 and 3.4.0 as part of my ubuntu 14 version. And so i changed the default version to Python 3.4.0

Comment: Right, so you'll need to run `python2 -m profile -s time file.py` as your code is Python 2. `print '%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec'` is Python 2 syntax.

Comment: I am getting errors.. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 199, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 192, in main
    runctx(code, globs, None, options.outfile, options.sort)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/cProfile.py", line 49, in runctx
    prof = prof.runctx(statement, globals, locals)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61622/discussion-between-jeeva-and-veedrac).

Answer (score 6):

**first i suggest use [profilers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers) module or [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) for this aim** .timeit provides a simple way to time small bits of Python code !

To profile a function that takes a single argument, you can do:

```
import cProfile
import re
cProfile.run('re.compile("foo|bar")')
```

Also you can use a [Decorator](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) like this that allows you to measure the execution times of dedicated methods  :

```
import time                                                

def measure_time(f):

  def timed(*args, **kw):
    ts = time.time()
    result = f(*args, **kw)
    te = time.time()

    print '%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec' % \
          (f.__name__, args, kw, te-ts)
    return result

return timed
```

You can use it like this :

```
  @measure_time
  def foo():
        #content of function
```

note that `f.__name__` return the name of function ! (in this case 'foo')

Comment: Sorry, i have never done this before. So, i have to add this measure_time function in the very starting of my program and add @measure_time before every function of mine? Am i right?

Comment: Is it possible to use profile or timeit for the whole program? And does that give me time taken by every function or i have to use them to find the time taken by one function once?

Comment: you need define the function in your `.py` and use `@measure_time` be fore any function for find those runtime !

Comment: its best to use profile and you can use it for all of your code

Comment: To profile a function that takes a single argument, you can do:

import cProfile
`import re
cProfile.run('re.compile("foo|bar")')`

Comment: read the more detail on wiki : https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#the-python-profilers

Comment: The problem is i am looking for something which will give me the time taken by each function in my module like func1 - time taken, func2 - time taken.. like this.. Thats why i am trying to understand if i can use profiler or timeit to get like this. Because, profiler or timeit looks for each function at a time, not a whole module at a time.

Comment: ok so as i write in answer you can use `re.comple` for add your function names